# 802.11n and network slowdown

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, airport, 802.11n

My router, 1st generation AirPort Extreme, is 802.11n 2.4GHz and 5.0GHz capable. Whenever I turn it on, instead of 802.11b/g/n the network slows down considerably within a few days.
This probably is because of bad firmware => the router running out of memory.

Do the newer generation AirPorts have the same issue with 802.11n? The 1st generation is quite old and I was surprised it actually supported 802.11n.

Comment: Have you bothered to check if there is new firmware for that device from the manufacturer?

Comment: I doubt it is even related to it being first generation. It sounds like a simple memory leak, or bad programming, in general...Bad firmware, and nothing more.

Comment: @KCotreau obviously... but they won't release another firmware update for it because its first generation

Comment: @Antwan In November, Apple just released firmware 7.5.2 for all eight of their existing 802.11n wireless router products (Extremes, Expresses, and Time Capsules), going all the way back to the first generation 802.11n AirPort Extreme from January 2007. Are you running 7.5.2 or something earlier?

Comment: @Spiff 7.5.2 and yet it is failing, its back to 802.11n/b/g and it doesn't slow down.. :/